# How can we add extra fields to the predefined user model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to know, that can we add extra fields to the predefined user model in Django or not?
If Yes, then how can we do that can anyone here can explain me.
Like I want to add the following fields

- Address
- zip code
- phone Number

And secondly, when I register a user it takes email, username, and password from me but when I login it takes the username and password, what I want is that it uses email and password to login.

Comment: This tells you everything you want to know: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: @michjinich the link you have shared in this u have made a one to one relationship for the profile fields, which i have already done what i want is to add those fields to the user model so that i don't have to make a one to one relationship

Comment: No, he details the different ways you can do it and how to do each one, as well as why to pick each one. Read the article.